# SQLAlchemy/PostgreSQL mutable, deduplicated array

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, sqlalchemy, mutable

After having read this [article](http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html) on implementing tags with PostgreSQL, I've decide to work with PostgreSQL's array datatype.

But from what I understand, there is not any built-in support for mutable arrays in SQLAlchemy. I would also like to prevent duplicates within these arrays (there isn't a any built-in 'set-like' datatype in PostgreSQL).

I'm having a hard time finding any concrete examples of how to use and manipulate SQLAlchemy arrays (declaratively) that are backed by PostgreSQL, even for simple append/update operations. How would I set the ARRAY and append to (if the to-be-appended string isn't a duplicate) to a SQLAlchemy ARRAY datatype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into exactly this problem.  The solution I used is to create a type that inherits from `sqlalchemy.ext.mutable.Mutable` and `set`, then wrap that in a type backed by `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY`.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import Mutable
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

modmethods = ['add', 'clear', 'difference_update', 'discard', 
              'intersection_update', 'pop', 'remove',
              'symmetric_difference_update', 'update',
              '__ior__', '__iand__', '__isub__', '__ixor__']

class MutableSet(Mutable, set):
    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, key, value):
        if not isinstance(value, cls):
            return cls(value)
        else:
            return value

def _make_mm(mmname):
    def mm(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            retval = getattr(set, mmname)(self, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            self.changed()
        return retval
    return mm

for m in modmethods:
    setattr(MutableSet, m, _make_mm(m))

del modmethods, _make_mm

def ArraySet(_type, dimensions=1):
    return MutableSet.as_mutable(ARRAY(_type, dimensions=dimensions))
```

This overrides the methods of `set` that can change the set's value by adding a call to `Mutable`'s  `changed` method, causing SQLAlchemy to flush the possibly changed value to the database.

Then, you declare this type in SQLAlchemy with the type that will be inside it; for instance, to declare it as a set of Integers:

```
Column(ArraySet(Integer))
```

Then, when you are using it, you can treat the value just like a standard Python set, with all the operators and methods unchanged.